# Выполнение команд терминала из функции postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql

Есть таблица files, в ней хранятся пути до файлов.
Необходимо написать триггер на удаление строки из этой таблицы. При удалении строки из таблицы files на сервере должен удалиться сам файл.
Как в функции postgres вызвать команды терминала, чтобы удалить файл?

Comment: Даже если бы так можно было делать, я бы не стал. Лучше бы завёл таблицу `ToDelete` и перенёс запись с именем файла в неё. А в кроне завёл бы процесс, который раз в час читал эту таблицу и удалял файлы.

Answer (score 0):

Не обязательно вызывать консоль для удаления файла. Можно выполнять триггеры на разных языках, [например на python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpython.html):

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;

CREATE FUNCTION deletefile() RETURNS trigger AS $$
import os
os.unlink(TD["old"]['path'])
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```